# Find median position points of duration events

Tags: arrays, matlab, duration, median

I have the following vector A:

```
A = [34 35 36 5 6 7 78 79 7 9 10 80 81 82 84 85 86 102 3 4 6 103 104 105 106 8 11 107 201 12 202 203 204];
```

For `n = 2`, I counted the elements larger or equal to 15 within `A`:

```
D = cellfun(@numel, regexp(char((A>=15)+'0'), [repmat('0',1,n) '+'], 'split'));
```

The above expression gives the following output as duration values:

```
D = [3 2 7 4 6] = [A(1:3) **stop** A(7:8) **stop** A(12:18) **stop** A(22:25) **stop** A(28:33)];
```

The above algorithm computes the duration values by counting the elements larger or equal to 15. The counting also allows less than 2 consecutive elements smaller than 15 (`n = 2`). The counter stops when there are 2 or more consecutive elements smaller than 15 and starts over at the next substring within `A`.

Eventually, I want a way to find the median position points of the duration events `A(1:3)`, `A(7:8)`, `A(12:18)`, `A(22:25)` and `A(28:33)`, which are correctly computed. The result should look like this:

```
a1 = round(median(A(1:3))) = 2; 
a2 = round(median(A(7:8))) = 8;
a3 = round(median(A(12:18))) = 15;
a4 = round(median(A(22:25))) = 24;
a5 = round(median(A(28:33))) = 31;
```

I edited the question to make it more clear, because the solution that was provided here assigns the last number within the row of 2 or more consecutive numbers smaller than 15 (3 in this case) after `A(1:3)` to the next substring `A(7:8)`and the same with the other substrings, therefore generating wrong duration values and in consequence wrong median position points of the duration events when `n = 2` or for any given even `n`.

Anyone has any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Given only `D`, this is impossible. `D` gives the lengths of the ranges but you will also need the starting positions. Can you provide the code you used to get `D`?

Comment: Should it not be `D(1) = A(1:3)`?

Comment: Please forgive me for not understanding, but should the first interval be between 1 and 8, because there are three numbers < 15 in that interval?  Similarly, interval 2 should be between 9 and 20, then 21 and 27 for interval 3... interval 4 doesn't exist because there's only one number < 15 here.

Comment: @Dan @rayryeng `A(1:6)` is correct. The first series of 3+ consecutive numbers <15 is `A(7:9)`. I'm guessing he stops the counter before the series and starts it when it's >15 again. @Bowecho It would be useful to have the processing function

Comment: If there are three **consecutive numbers smaller than 15**... Numbers 1 through 6 don't exhibit this property.  There is a chain of numbers... 34-36, but none of these are < 15.  The only number that's < 15 here is 5, but that doesn't constitute a chain of three consecutive numbers. Bowecho, please verify our comments and correct your post if required.  We all have differing definitions on what is correct in your post.

Comment: @rayryeng I think he means 3 numbers less than 15 that are consecutive in the vector, not consecutive in their values but only in their positions. Hence `[7 9 10]` count because they are all less than 15

Comment: So, all consecutive elements under 3 in a row which are smaller or equal to 15 will be considered in the counting, like this: `D = 34->A(1) 35->A(2) 36->A(3) 5->A(4) 78->A(5) 79->A(6) stop 80->A(10) 81->A(11) 82->A(12) 84->A(13) 85->A(14) 86->A(15) 102->A(16) stop... etc `

Comment: I will edit my question and add the code to generate D

Comment: Is my explanation more clear now, @rayryeng and @Dan? Sorry I wasn't more clear maybe from the start.

Comment: That makes more sense, but I see you have an answer.  Good luck!