# Find median position points of duration evens within array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, duration

I have the following vector `A`:

```
A = [34 35 36 5 6 7 78 79 7 9 10 80 81 82 84 85 86 102 3 4 6 103 104 105 106 8 11 107 201 12 202 203 204];
```

For `n = 2`, I counted the elements larger or equal to 15 within `A`:

```
D = cellfun(@numel, regexp(char((A>=15)+'0'), [repmat('0',1,n) '+'], 'split'));
```

The above expression gives the following output as duration values:

```
D = [3 2 7 4 6] = [A(1:3) **stop** A(7:8) **stop** A(12:18) **stop** A(22:25) **stop** A(28:33)];
```

The above algorithm computes the duration values by counting the elements larger or equal to 15. The counting also allows less than 2 consecutive elements smaller than 15 (`n = 2`) within each duration event. The counter stops when there are 2 or more consecutive elements smaller than 15 and starts over at the next substring within `A`.

The solution provided here [Find median position points of duration events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990908/find-median-position-points-of-duration-events/31991767?noredirect=1#comment51921452_31991767) assigns the last number within the row of 2 or more consecutive numbers smaller than 15 (3 in this case) after `A(1:3)` to the next substring `A(7:8)`and the same with the other substrings, which is not the correct way to compute the duration events.

I want a way to find the median position points of the duration events `A(1:3)`, `A(7:8)`, `A(12:18)`, `A(22:25)` and `A(28:33)`, which are correctly computed. The result should look like this:

```
a1 = round(median(A(1:3))) = 2; 
a2 = round(median(A(7:8))) = 8;
a3 = round(median(A(12:18))) = 15;
a4 = round(median(A(22:25))) = 24;
a5 = round(median(A(28:33))) = 31;
```

Comment: can you explain why round(median(A(1:3))) = 2 ? do you only want the median of the index?

Comment: @Bowecho - reposting questions is not how it works here. In the worst case moderators will take actions. What you should do: clarify your first question and add as much details as possible and then offer a bounty. This way your question gets full attention for a week and you surely will get an answer.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I will do try to do that as well then.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, it might be stupid (to use the while loop...), but basically solves the problem.

The process is to first add every 2 consecutive integers, if their sum is less than 30, then there must be 2 or more integers less than 15 in between. Where the sum is greater than 30, there can be 1 or 0 integers less than 15 in between. -NOTE: This is only true when you have positive numbers, if negatives are present than this solution is wrong!

```
A = [34 35 36 5 6 7 78 79 7 9 10 80 81 82 84 85 86 102 3 4 6 103 104 105 106 8 11 107 201 12 202 203 204];
A1 = A(1:end-1);
A2 = A(2:end);
B = A1+A2;
C = find(B<30);
Cmod = [1,C,size(A,2)];
counter = 1;
j = 1;

while counter < size(Cmod,2)
    temp = Cmod(:,counter):Cmod(:,counter+1)-1;
    if size(temp,2) < 2
        counter=counter+1;
    else
        a(j) = round(median(temp(3:end)));
        counter = counter+1;
        j=j+1;
    end
end
a(1) = a(1)-1; %this compensate the position shift in A1 and A2
a(end) = a(end)+1;
```

output is vector a which reads:

```
 a =

 >>2     8    15    24    31
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to generalize the solution, meaning I want to easily be able to change the number of consecutive elements smaller than 15 that go in between.

Comment: So I am not sure how I could generalize your solution.

Comment: @Bowecho The solution only works for 2 consecutive elements, as you have not specified you needed a general solution, this solution is quite efficient (except for the while loop).

Comment: I need a general solution, though.

Comment: @Bowecho Then please edit your question to request for a general solution. I simply offered my take on a stated question where I found a rather interesting way to solve.

Comment: Yes, my apologizes, but when one is giving an example of how the algorithm works, the expected programmatic solution should be general.